# Image upload takes previous temp file to upload in PHP

Tags: php, image, file, file-upload, upload

Here I have the problem with uploading image in PHP.

The problem is that when first time I upload the image file it works fine.
But when I am trying to upload the file second time without page refresh it takes first image name and upload it.

What is the problem and how can it be resolved?

```
$name = $_FILES['ImageFile']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'];

$path = "public/www/uploads/";
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
        $response = '';
        if(strlen($name)) {

            list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {

                if($size<(1024*1024)) {

                    $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {

                                                $response = "<img src='public/www/uploads/".$actual_image_name."?parm=".time()."' class='preview'>";

                    } else { 
                        $response = "failed";
                    }
                } else { 
                    $response = "Image file size max 1 MB";                 
                }
            } else {
                $response = "Invalid file format..";    
            }
        } else {
            $response = "Please select image..!";
        }
```

Here, `$response` is a variable that used to get status.

Comment: Can't see a problem in above code. Maybe more relevant code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using some sort of AJAX to call this function.

You might need to find a way to reset the $_FILES array at the end of this function... maybe something like this would help:

```
$_FILES = array();
```

Otherwise, because there is no (apparent) page refresh happening after the file upload (as you mentioned,) I'm thinking that the $_FILES variable has no chance of being naturally reset (as would happen if you weren't using AJAX here.)

Comment: I have try it. but so solution found.